# how to render a grouped object into a table grouped by column using Lodash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops, lodash

I have an array that looks like this

```
[{ id: '1234', year: 2019 , name: 'Test 1- 2019', rate: 1}, 
 { id: '1234', year: 2020, name: 'Test 2 - 2020',  rate: 2 },
 { id: '1234', year: 2020, name: 'Test 3 - 2020', rate : 3 } 
 ...]
```

and I  want to render it on table that looks like this

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr> 
    <th> 2019 </th>
    <th> 2020 </th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td> Test 1- 2019</td> 
    <td> Test 2- 2020 </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  </td> 
    <td> Test 3- 2020 </td> 
  </tr>

</table>
```

any thoughts? Thanks in Advance! :)

EDIT: Here's what I have so far:

```html
    <table border="1">
      <tr> 
        <th> 2019 </th>
        <th> 2020 </th> 
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td> Test 1- 2019</td> 
          <td>  </td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> </td> 
          <td> Test 2- 2020 </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>  </td> 
        <td> Test 3- 2020 </td> 
      </tr>

    </table>
```

I'm using a simple v-for (vueJS) to loop through the array.

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
     <td> ...year </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="item in arr">
     <td> {{ item.year == "2019" ? item.name : ""}} </td>
     <td> {{ item.year == "2020" ? item.name : ""}} </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what you want to do with the input data. Also, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Edited my answer for more details

Comment: I don't think that you should focus on the template. Focus on having the structure that you wish in JS before adding Vue to it. It's not a Vue issue here, more of how to properly format your objects/arrays.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a Vue issue. I'm trying to find way to flatten the array to accommodate for empty spaces between rows.

Comment: interesting. i can give a solution but not sure of a cleaner way to do it since it requires a grouping, taking the values and zipping

Comment: @cmgchess any insights would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @LexDacs something like https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/bGKgBzJ but im sure there must be a better way

Comment: @LexDacs i also havent done vue so im not sure whether to use method or computed props

Comment: this is an interesting scenario and i think can also apply to angularjs/angular as well to render tables using 'for' directives. a better title would be how to render a grouped object into a table grouped by column

Comment: It's really interesting scenario. I received the actual data from an API where data are grouped by year. It wouldn't be neat looking just to the first attempt with null rows on every row.

Thanks again for the help. I'll change the instruction per your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer posted by @cmgchess

It uses groupBy then get the Object values and zip using lodash

shorturl.at/cdxQ6